# Displaying multiple terminals in a single window

Tags: terminal, htop

I'm trying to setup a dedicated computer for displaying server statuses, and I'd like to showing the output of `htop` for about 5 servers simultaneously in a grid of terminals.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

I know how to use terminal applications like Terminator to manually setup split terminal windows, but this needs to be configured automatically. I don't want to have to manually setup Terminator every time. I imagine I'm not the first person to want to do something like this, but I'm not sure what this task is called, so my Google searches aren't finding much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tmux` to split panes in the same console window.  If you're on a Mac, tmux is built into iTerm2.

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5752901/428779) describes how to set it up and save the session info.